# Error: this is coming while using git bash for calling atom . any solution regarding this?

Tags: git-bash

Here is the warnings (errors?) I see:

```
C:\Users\Eshaan\AppData\Roaming\npm\jest -> C:\Users\Eshaan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jest\bin\jest.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\jest\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

How can I avoid those messages?

Comment: Looks like it's a warning message and can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

From [angular/angular-cli issue 8551](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8551):

> You can ignore this warning: `fs-events` is required on macOS.